# Can I call a swift function that throws in an if statement?

Tags: swift

Say I have a function called:

```
func myFunction() throws -> Bool {
    // ...
    return true
}
```

Is there a syntax I am unaware of to use it like so:

```
if aFlag && try myFunction() {
   // do this
}
```

When I compile this, it fails of course because it says a "try cannot appear to the right of a non-assignment operation". Is there a way to make this work or will I have to go with my current solution of:

```
if aFlag {
    let result = try myFunction()
    if result {
        // do this
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check `try?` instead of `try`? Not sure it will work but it's worth checking.

Comment: Are you intending to catch, propagate or absorb this error? Because you cannot use `try` without an accompanying `do`-`catch`, unless you're using it in a function that `throws`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `try?` to handle an error by converting it to an optional value, and combine with the `nil` coalescing operator to supply e.g. `false` as concrete value in case the call throws (-> treated as `nil`)

```
func myFunction() throws -> Bool {
    return true
}

let aFlag = true

if aFlag, (try? myFunction()) ?? false {
    print("Function call succeeded and returned 'true'!")
}

/* or ...
if aFlag && (try? myFunction()) ?? false { ... } */

/* or, optionally bind the return value and use as predicate if non-nil ...
if aFlag, let anotherFlag = (try? myFunction()), anotherFlag { ... } */
```

This will, however, supress the error thrown, which makes it kind of questionable for `myFunction()` to be a throwing one in the first place. Perhaps you rather want a function that simply returns `nil` in the cases you treat as erroneous in your throwing function?

Comment: True, I may have just changed the method to not throw. I was converting some code to be similar and trying to make it work that way intrigued me.

Comment: @kailoon out of a technical perspective discussions such as this can indeed be interesting; but generally, if supressing thrown errors as `nil` (in methods that are yours), it might be a good point to stop and re-consider if the method needs to be a throwing one (or if the thrown errors needs to be caught and handled rather than supressed).

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3, you can use `,` rather than `&&`, e.g.

```
if aFlag, try myFunction() {
    print("OK")
}
```